# Student with TRNC visa

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, northern-cyprus, zimbabwean-citizens

My daughter holds a TRNC student visa she is coming home to Southouse Africa for summer break can she pass through any airport in Turkey example  Istanbul airport without problems. She is not going into Turkey but just use the airport.

Comment: What is her itinerary?

Comment: Coming home from where? What is the itinerary? Why Turkey?

Comment: Zimbabwean citizens seem to need a transit visa. I could not find any info about the TRNC student visa, which may be accepted, since the only way to fly to TRNC is via Turkey.

Comment: @TomasBy Zimbabwean or South African? Does it make a difference? Do not hesitate to edit the question to improve it so that we can reopen it. ;)